# Skype for linux blurred fonts on xenial

Tags: xubuntu, fonts, xfce, skype, antialiasing

I'm using Skype for linux (8.11.0.4). All the fonts and the interface looks "blurred".

I'm using Xubuntu, `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` with `XFCE 4.12`.

Skypeforlinux is the only application with this problem. To me it looks like an application built with [ElectronJs](https://electronjs.org/).

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is indeed an electron app... I found that launching it with this command line options the rendering looks better.

`skypeforlinux --disable-gpu --enable-lcd-text`